# PHP - make dynamic navbar

Tags: php, codeigniter

My Navbar (HTML only):

```
<ul class="navbar-nav m-auto">
  <li class="nav-item active"><a href="<?= base_url('Home')?>" class="nav-link">Beranda</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="<?= base_url('Karya')?>" class="nav-link">Paket Wisata</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="<?= base_url('Foto')?>" class="nav-link">Foto</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="<?= base_url('Contact')?>" class="nav-link">Kontak</a></li>
</ul>
```

---

My Navbar (php-version)

```
<ul class="navbar-nav m-auto">
  <li <?php if ($active=='beranda') { echo 'class="nav-item active"'; } ?>><a href="<?= base_url('Home')?>" class="nav-link">Beranda</a></li>
  <li <?php if ($active=='karya') { echo 'class="nav-item active"'; } ?>><a href="<?= base_url('Karya')?>" class="nav-link">Paket Wisata</a></li>
  <li <?php if ($active=='foto') { echo 'class="nav-item active"'; } ?>><a href="<?= base_url('Foto')?>" class="nav-link">Foto</a></li>
  <li <?php if ($active=='kontak') { echo 'class="nav-item active"'; } ?>><a href="<?= base_url('Contact')?>" class="nav-link">Kontak</a></li>
</ul>
```

---

The PHP-version of the Navbar isn't working: please help me

Comment: can you screenshot your full code?

Comment: It's best to include the [relevant code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the question itself; [no screenshots please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: What URLs are generated by your `base_url()` calls? What is the value of `$active`?

Answer (score 0):

> you forgot to place else statement try this

```
<ul class="navbar-nav m-auto">
    <li <?=($active=='beranda')?'class="nav-item active"':'nav-item';?>><a href="<?= base_url('Home')?>" class="nav-link">Beranda</a></li>
   <li <?=($active=='karya')?'class="nav-item active"':'nav-item';?>><a href="<?= base_url('Karya')?>" class="nav-link">Paket Wisata</a></li>
  <li <?=($active=='foto')?'class="nav-item active"':'nav-item';?>><a href="<?= base_url('Foto')?>" class="nav-link">Foto</a></li>
   <li <?=($active=='kontak')?'class="nav-item active"':'nav-item';?>><a href="<?= base_url('Contact')?>" class="nav-link">Kontak</a></li>
</ul>
```